# Do any RAF helicopters have skids instead of wheels?

Tags: military, helicopter, aircraft-identification, uk

**Are there any current, or Cold War-era, Royal Air Force helicopters fitted with skids as standard?**

I seem to recall hearing, when I served, that RAF helicopters only ever had wheels, whereas skids were the exclusive preserve of the Army Air Corps.

This related [answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/65954/why-do-some-helicopters-have-wheels-instead-of-skids) says that the choice "*seems to be that they are chosen based on the mission profile of the helicopter as well as the size to some extent.*" But, in my experience, both the RAF and the AAC support infantry operations in fairly equal measure, and the RAF [Wessex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Westland_Wessex) and AAC [Lynx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Westland_Lynx) have fairly similar weights.

Comment: Prior research?

Answer (score 4):

Look no further than the [Defence Helicopter Flying School](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defence_Helicopter_Flying_School), which operates at RAF Shawbury, which uses (or has used) at least 3 helicopters equipped with skids:

- [Westland Gazelle HT3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%C3%A9rospatiale_Gazelle)
- [Bell Griffin HT1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_412)
- [Jupiter HT1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eurocopter_EC145)

In addition the current list of [active RAF aircraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_active_United_Kingdom_military_aircraft) lists the [Bell 412](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_412) (note the Army Air Corps use the Bell 212)

Finally an [historic list of RAF aircraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_aircraft_of_the_Royal_Air_Force) lists the [Bell H13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_H-13_Sioux), the [Eurocopter AS350](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eurocopter_AS350_%C3%89cureuil) and the [Eurocopter AS355](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eurocopter_AS355_%C3%89cureuil_2).